# Why Hibernate STRING can not be resolved?

Tags: java, hibernate

I just downloaded new release of Hibernate 4.0.1 final release. It is very strange that when I type the following code:

```
Hibernate.STRING
```

The eclipse IDE showing an error on the STRING keyword. I am sure that I have the hibernate jar in my build path, and the following code has been included as well:

```
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
```

I just wonder why this could happen?

Comment: Does `import org.hibernate.Hibernate;` shows as error as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because [that field doesn't exist in 4.0](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html).

The [field documentation in 3.5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#STRING) says this:

> **Deprecated.** *see http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5138*

You can now use [`StandardBasicTypes.STRING`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/StandardBasicTypes.html#STRING) (which is pretty much [`StringType.INSTANCE`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/StringType.html#INSTANCE)).