# Token SQL92 not supported

Tags: java, jdbc, hibernate-criteria

I have some troubles in my app using sqlRestriction method:

This is my movie class:

```
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "movie_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "movie_seq", sequenceName = "movie_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    public long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String str_name = "";

...

}
```

When i do something like that (dummy test):

```
List<Movie> movies = session.createCriteria(Movie.class)
        .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1 in (1)"))
        .list();
```

It Works perfectly.

My second test (changing the Restriction):

```
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("Movie.id in (166,171)"))
```

And my third test

```
add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{Movie}.id in (166,171)"))
```

Both of them fails in the same way:

```
ERROR: Token SQL92 no soportado en la posición: 345
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Token SQL92 no soportado en la posición: 345
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.handleODBC(OracleSql.java:1275)
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edited**

I tried :

```
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.id in (?, ?)", new Long[]{166L,171L}, new Type[]{Hibernate.Long, Hibernate.Long}) )
```

And i got this : "Long cannot be resolved or is not a field"

It seems "Hibernate.{AnyType}" is deprecated, see this link: [Why Hibernate STRING can not be resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119672/why-hibernate-string-can-not-be-resolved)

i tried this instead:

```
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.id in (?, ?)", new Long[]{166L,171L}, new Type[]{LongType.INSTANCE, LongType.INSTANCE}) )
```

But I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "THIS_"."ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: just curious was the latest with `public long id` or `public Long id`? but it seems that  alias might not be set correctly

Comment: Finally the error was just detected. I was using the name of the hibernate table/field names (I mean "id") it was changed to "pk". and it worked!.

.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("pk in (?, ?)", new Long[]{166L,171L}, new Type[]{LongType.INSTANCE, LongType.INSTANCE}) )

I thought I have to use the HQL table/field names. But the names/fields of the phisicall table is the correct!.

Answering your question: Im using this:
@Column(name = "pk")
public long id;

I appreciate a lot your help

Comment: of course. i missed `@Column(name = "pk")` and `sqlRestriction` it IS native sql NOT JPQL :D. well, learned something new

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you use the alias correctly. Try following

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.pk in (?, ?)", new Long[]{166L,171L}, new Type[]{Hibernate.Long, Hibernate.Long}) )
```

Count of `?` needs to the same as the size of given array so the `(?,?)` should be constructed & appended dynamically based on the array passed. As well as the type array.

EDIT: the id field name is not `id` but `pk`, missed `@Column(name = "pk")` in origal answer. Newer hibernate versions have no more 'Hibernate.Long' but use `LongType.INSTANCE` instead.

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.pk in (?, ?)", new Long[]{166L,171L}, new Type[]{LongType.INSTANCE, LongType.INSTANCE}) )
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it seems "Hibernate.Long" is deprecated. I think I have to use "LongType.INSTANCE". However, i received this error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: [J cannot be cast to java.lang.Long", maybe because it is an array.. But anyway. I tried with only a value (no an array) : sqlRestriction("{alias}.id = ?", 166L, LongType.INSTANCE)
And I got this error: ORA-00904: "THIS_"."ID": invalid identifier

Comment: did it work, even `Hibernate.Long` is deprecated ? How about `Long.class` then ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment.. Answering your last comment. Yes it fails. "Hibernate.INTEGER cannot be resolved". What package is it imported from? ¿import org.hibernate.Hibernate?

Comment: just realized also: change primitive `long` to `Long`, the type of `id`

Comment: using Long.class : The method sqlRestriction(String, Object[], Type[]) in the type Restrictions is not applicable for the arguments (String, Long[], Class<Long>)

Comment: Well. I changed the type of id in my Movie class (public Long id;). then i tried : .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.id in ?", new Long[]{166L,171L}, Long.class) )
But i got : The method sqlRestriction(String, Object[], Type[]) in the type Restrictions is not applicable for the arguments (String, Long[], Class<Long>)

Comment: `org.hibernate.Hibernate` for `Hibernate.Long` i guess is the package.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I was using the name of the hibernate table/field names (I mean "id") it was changed to "pk". and it worked!.

```
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("pk in (?, ?)", new Long[]{166L,171L}, new Type[]{LongType.INSTANCE, LongType.INSTANCE}) )
```

I thought I have to use the HQL table/field names. But the names/fields of the phisicall table is the correct!.